# IEnumerable.Except to display differences in textbox c sharp

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I am new to C # and I am getting stuck on using `IEnumerable.Except`. What I am trying to do is get the difference of 2 sequences of 100 random dice rolls using 2 die. I have my die rolls and totals good to go.

My differences are not showing in my txtDifference textbox at all. I am not sure if I have it placed in the correct spot or if it isn't written correctly. The code itself has no errors and I am not sure how to fix it. Here is my code, any help is greatly appreciated!!

```
 private void btnRoll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        // create random  and lists        
        randomizer = new Random();
        List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
        List<int> secondNumbers = new List<int>();

        // for loop for 1st sequence 
        for (i = 1; i < 100; i++)
        {
                string mssg = string.Empty;
                die1 = randomizer.Next(1, 7);
                die2 = randomizer.Next(1, 7);
                dieRoll1.Text = die1.ToString();
                dieRoll2.Text = die2.ToString();
                rollValue = die1 + die2;

                // add to collection.
                numbers.Add(i);

                // display results
                txtResults.Text += string.Concat(dieRoll1.Text, "               ", dieRoll2.Text, "               ", rollValue, "              ", Environment.NewLine);
        }

        //loop for second sequence. 
        for (i = 1; i < 100; i++)
        {
            string mssg = string.Empty;
            die1 = randomizer.Next(1, 7);
            die2 = randomizer.Next(1, 7);
            dieRoll1.Text = die1.ToString();
            dieRoll2.Text = die2.ToString();
            rollValue = die1 + die2;
            
            //add to collection. 
            secondNumbers.Add(i);

            //display results in second text box
            txtResults2.Text += string.Concat(dieRoll1.Text, "              ", dieRoll2.Text, "              ", rollValue, "              ", Environment.NewLine);
        }

        // IEnumerable for comparison between the two sequences 
        IEnumerable<int> onlyInFirstSet = numbers.Except(secondNumbers);

        //foreach to display the differences between the sequences 
        foreach (int number in onlyInFirstSet)
            txtDifference.Text = number.ToString(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both loops iterate from 1 to 100. Then, in both cases, you're adding the value of `i` to the lists... which means both lists end up with the values 1 to 100 in them.

```
numbers.Add(i);
secondNumbers.Add(i);
```

So the following line of code always results in an empty list. It removes the second collection of numbers 1 to 100 from the first collection of numbers 1 to 100.

```
IEnumerable<int> onlyInFirstSet = numbers.Except(secondNumbers);
```

Instead, add the `rollValue` value to your list, not the variable your `foreach` loop is iterating over:

```
rollValue = die1 + die2;

//add to collection.
numbers.Add(rollValue);
```

Same goes for your second loop and collection:

```
rollValue = die1 + die2;

//add to collection. 
secondNumbers.Add(rollValue);
```

Comment: Grant, Comparing the rollValue does make much more sense when you explained it and that seemed to make it work!! I really appreciate your time and help!

Answer (score 3):

`txtDifference.Text = number.ToString();` will show only last number in the set as you are overwriting the value on each iteration.

I think you are looking for showing all of the values:

```
txtDifference.Text = String.Join(",", onlyInFirstSet);
```

Comment: I tried that and it is giving me an error with the 'txtDifference.Text = String.Join(",", onlyInFirstSetnumber.Select(n => n.ToString()));' the issue is saying the name doesn't exist in the current context, so I tried it using onlyInFirstSet.Select because that gave no errors, but it still didn't display the results.

Comment: Thank you Grant. The issue is still the same, it does not display the results into the textbox. I am curious if it is something to do with my Lists? Maybe the numbers are not going to the list so the IEnumerable has nothing to compare and that is why it is not displaying anything?